# Is it possible to inset a panel into a BoxSizer in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to make something that looks like an installer without actually installing anything ( I am using it to explore wxPython) .And right now I'm trying to put a panel on another panel, but when ever I do that the window shows up grey and only the corner of one button shows .

```
import wx

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def initUI(self):
        vbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(self,-1,'This is Panel One'),0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        vbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show(True)


class Gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)


        self.initUI()
        self.tTips()


    def initUI(self):
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.vbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)

        ##This is what im having trouble with
        p1=PanelOne(self)
        self.vbox.Add(p1,3,wx.ALL,10)
        ##

        btnBox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) #This Sizer is for the box that will hold the next and back buttons.

        backBtn=wx.Button(panel,-1,'&Back')# back button
        backBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onBack)
        btnBox.Add(backBtn,0,wx.ALL,10)
        nextBtn=wx.Button(panel,-1,'&Next')# next button
        nextBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onNext)
        btnBox.Add(nextBtn,0,wx.ALL,10)

        self.vbox.Add(btnBox)


        self.vbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.Show(True)
    def onNext(self,e):
        pass
    def onBack(self,e):
        pass

    def tTips(self):
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    gui=Gui(None,-1,'Title Yo')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the wx.wizard.Wizard widget as it basically already has everything you need builtin. You can read about it [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/) or you can see an example in the wxPython demo (which can be downloaded from the wxPython website). Of course, rolling your own wizard is a lot more flexible. I created a skeleton to show one way to do it on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/). That should get you started.

Your problem is that you don't add the wx.EXPAND flag when you add the panel to the sizer and you don't call SetSizer for the panel or the frame.